# Rename SQL table test[']2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Can anyone tell me how I rename this table?

```
test[']2
```

I have tried `EXEC sp_rename 'test['']2', 'abc'` in every combination.. and it fails with `Syntax error parsing SQL identifier`

I have tried the following

```
EXEC sp_rename 'test['']2', 'abc';
EXEC sp_rename 'test[]'']2', 'abc';
EXEC sp_rename '[test['']2]', 'abc';
EXEC sp_rename '[test[]'']2]', 'abc';
EXEC sp_rename [test[]']2], 'abc';
EXEC sp_rename [test[']2], 'abc';
```

has anyone any other ideas?

---

SOLUTION

In case you come across this same problem and want to rename a table safely, here is a link to the code

It is based on using the object_id of the table which you get from sys.tables, but you could easily change the code to use a table name

[Rename MSSQL Table](http://snipt.org/xoYm)

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that. MSSQL 2008 R2

Answer (score 1):

Found it!

Id missed one combo out. The answer is

`exec sp_rename '[test ['']] 2]', 'abc';`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
exec sp_rename '"test['']"', 'abc'
```

Comment: thanks shark but i got the answer. missed a combination out :) `exec sp_rename '[test ['']] 2]', 'abc';`

Comment: @Christian no problem :) there's a few ways to skin that proverbial cat.

Answer (score -1):

Can you check QUOTED_IDENTIFIER setting

Comment: Running DBCC UserOptions, QUOTED_IDENTIFIER has a value of SET